# Is there an advantage to knowing at compile time the number of iterations of a for loop?

Tags: c, optimization, opencl

Is there some advantage to knowing at compile time how many iterations should be done of a for loop?

For example, in some situations, can the compiler produce an executable that will run faster given this:

```c
#define ITERATIONS 10
int foo()
{
    for (int i=0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
        do_something();
    }
}
```

than given this:

```c
int foo(int iterations)
{
    for (int i=0; i < iterations; i++){
        do_something();
    }
}
```

If this is not universally the case, what are those situations?

My concern is in the specific case of OpenCL, so I'm also interested to know if this is different to C.

Comment: Most of the issues are mentioned in the answers. I want to add that if you're developing in OpenCL for NVIDIA target, loop-unrolling definitely improves the performance. So if you define the loop iterations and proper pragma (as suggested by Alex Placet) you get higher performance. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested in a fairly realistic situation using GCC. When the number of loops is known at compile time, I get this:

```
.L2:
    call    do_something
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L2
```

When it's not, I get this:

```
.L6:
    call    do_something
    addl    $1, %ebx
    cmpl    %ebp, %ebx
    jne .L6
```

So it was able to optimize the fixed number of iterations slightly better by changing to a count down to zero loop rather than a count up loop. If nothing else, this uses a bit less code cache.

With higher optimizations levels, it fully unrolls a loop that invokes an external function ten times. Presumably, it wouldn't do that unless it thought it was better. And it surely can't do that if the number of iterations is unknown.

Short answer: Fixed numbers of iterations give compilers more options. That should result in very slightly better code at least some of the time.

Comment: So it just adds 1 extra instruction. In other words, it doesn't make sense to do any manual optimization in this case. 1 extra instruction would most likely not even matter in a hard real time system. And in some OpenGL desktop program, it wouldn't matter the slightest.

Comment: If it requires specific optimization effort, it's almost definitely not worth it on typical modern commodity computers. OpenCL might actually make more of a difference since the compiler may need to generate an "execution strategy" for the code. I'm not that familiar with OpenCL. If you're specifically interested, it might be worth asking a more OpenCL-specific question.

Comment: It seems, as per @AlexPlacet's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954526/709852), that GPUs seriously benefit from being able to unroll the loop.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: It makes sense that it would make a bigger difference on a GPU. GPUs take a heavier penalty than CPUs when they have to make branching decisions. Also, CPUs typically pipeline at run time, GPUs typically at compile time. It's much harder to pipeline a loop whose count is indeterminate. (And if the compiler partially unrolls, it has to deal with the possibility the loop count won't divide evenly. If it knows the loop runs ten times, it can unroll by five evenly. Or unless by 3 and know there's exactly 1 leftover rather than having to compute it.)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it depends on the compiler. But effectively it allows the unrolling of loops.
Here is an [Intel example](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/opencl/optimization-guide/Note_on_Loops.htm) and a [AMD example](http://developer.amd.com/Resources/hc/OpenCLZone/programming/ImageConvolutionOpenCL/pages/ImageConvolutionUsingOpenCL_4.aspx).

With NVIDIA you need to had in your kernel: `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_nv_pragma_unroll : enable`.

So you can use a flag when you compiling, like: `-DITERATIONS=10`

Comment: Ah, that Intel link is good. The answer is "Allowing loop unrolling is a good thing for OpenCL.". Thanks!

Comment: @HenryGomersall It is definitely worth noting that loop unrolling could end up causing your code to be slower depending on the compiler and the occupancy achieved on the device.  For CPUs, loop unrolling typically helps, but for GPUs optimizations do not always lead to faster code (determining the best optimization for a GPU code is NP-hard, I believe).

Comment: @KLee1 Presumably the GPU compiler has some idea about what to do regarding loop unrolling. It's not like I'd _make_ it unroll the loop, so just adding more info seems like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialise `i`,

```
for (int i; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
```

is undefined behaviour and allows the compiler to entirely skip the loop ;)

Apart from that, if the number of iterations is known at compile time, the compiler can completely unroll the loop, for example, which can make a big difference (if the loop body is cheap).

Comment: That's the most obvious difference -- if the number of iterations is known at compile time, the compiler has the option to totally unroll the loop. It will definitely do this if the number of iterations is 0 or 1. Whether there's a way to optimize a typical 10 iteration loop is a platform specific question.

Comment: I corrected the initialisation (it was just me writing code directly into SO).

Comment: I suspected as much, @HenryGomersall, hence the ;).

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a lot on the compiler and optimization settings you are using. Most likely, knowing the amount of loops will allow the compiler to unroll the loop and get rid of the branches and parameter i.

This is however completely compiler dependent, so don't count on it. But if you have a modern compiler, chances are big it will improve speed.

edit:

I read over the obvious uninitialized i, but you probably did too...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of gcc-4.5.3, with `do_something() {printf("hello world")}`:

- Without optimization or at `-O2`, the compiler does not unroll either loop.
- At `-O4`, for the pre-known number of iterations only, the compiler unrolls the loop and inlines `do_something()`:

.

```
foo:
...
.L4:
        addl    $1, %ebx
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    __printf_chk
        cmpl    %ebx, %esi
        jg      .L4

main:
...
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    __printf_chk
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    __printf_chk
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    __printf_chk
...
```